# Using a feature of the WinAPI designed for Vista while maintaining backwards compatibility with XP?

Tags: c, winapi

My project right now works with XP and up, WINVER == 0x501 . However, for those using Vista and up, I would like to do:

```
case WM_MOUSEHWHEEL:
```

in my WNDPROC

However when I try to build that I get undeclared identifier WM_MOUSEHWHEEL

is there a way to maintain compatibility with XP, but to let Vista & 7 users have this capability?

Thanks

Comment: good question. The quick&dirty way would be to look up the value  of WM_MOUSEHWHEEL and use it directly, ie #ifndef WM_MOUSEHWHEEL #define WM_MOUSEHWHEEL xxx #endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
#ifndef WM_MOUSEHWHEEL
#define WM_MOUSEHWHEEL                  0x020E
#endif
```

There, that should be correct

NOTE: I originally answered WM_MOUSEWHEEL, not WM_MOUSEHWHEEL.  Correct. :P

Comment: It's `MOUSEHWHEEL`, not `MOUSEWHEEL`.